# Xamarin - Facebook Login Response Activity Change

Tags: c#, xamarin, oauth, xamarin.android, facebook-login

I am using OAuth to login using Facebook in my Xamarin Cross platform App (Native Android at the moment). I try to pass a Uri request and then trying to get a response. This response procedure is where the app starts misbehaving.

Please look at the code below:

```
var request = new OAuth2Request("GET", new Uri("https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=first_name,last_name,gender,email"), null, eventArgs.Account);

                            var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
                            //Goes to the white screen here

                            var obj = JObject.Parse(response.GetResponseText());

                            var id = obj["id"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");

                            //Having the Facebook user id as the password
                            loginPage.ID = id;

                            var firstname = obj["first_name"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");
                            var lastName = obj["last_name"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");
                            var gender = obj["gender"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");
                            //var ret = App.Database.GetProfile(Email, Password);
                            loginPage.Email = "Facebook";
                            //var email = "Facebook";


                            //activity = this.Context as Activity;


                            //await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Welcome", firstname + " " + lastName, "Thank you!");
                            string username = firstname + lastName;
                            string usrname = firstname + " " + lastName;
                            //await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Profile completion", "As this is your first time, please complete your profile", "OK");

                            var ret = App.Database.GetProfile(username, id);

                            //First time user, then complete profile via UserProfileINC page
                            if (ret != null)
                            {
                                await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new MenuPage(ret.Email, ret.Password));
                            }//Second or more time user, then view UserProfile page
                            else
                            {
                                await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new UserProfileINC(ret.Email, ret.Password, usrname));
                            }

                            //NavigationPage nav = new NavigationPage(new UserProfileINC(email, id, username));
                            //activity.StartActivity(auth.GetUI(activity));

                            //await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new UserProfileINC(email, id, username));


                            //activity.StartActivity(auth.GetUI(activity));
                            //OAuthConfig.SuccessfulLoginAction.Invoke();

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Cancel!", "Login Canceled", "Go Back!");
                            // The user cancelled
                        }
                    };


                    activity.StartActivity(auth.GetUI(activity));
```

It should go to either one of these pages in the `if else` statement :

```
//First time user, then complete profile via UserProfileINC page
                            if (ret != null)
                            {
                                await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new MenuPage(ret.Email, ret.Password));
                            }//Second or more time user, then view UserProfile page
                            else
                        {
                            await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new UserProfileINC(ret.Email, ret.Password, usrname));
                        }
```

However, all i see after the authentication is a white blank page. If i press the back button on my android device on this page i can successfully see the page that should have been navigated to on the first place.

Comment: I saw your code `await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new MenuPage(ret.Email, ret.Password));`, are you using Xamarin.Forms PCL? This code is in your Android project right?

Comment: Yes, i am using Xamarin Forms PCL. And the code is indeed in my Android Project. I apologize for missing to add this crucial information in the question.